# Apexcharts scatter dots is hidden under eachother

Tags: javascript, apexcharts

I am using a scatter diagram with apexcharts like this: https://apexcharts.com/javascript-chart-demos/scatter-charts/basic/.

My problem is that if there is two or more datapoints with the exact same value, they will be stacked above eachother and therefore only one is shown and the other ones are completely hidden (not shown on hover either).

Is there any function to make them all viewable even if they have the same value? Maybe some sort of offset if more of the same value or some tooltip showing number of layers or something?

Code:

```
  var options = {
          series: [{
          name: "Data A",
          data: [
          [16, 5], [16, 5, [16, 5], [15, 2], [14, 1], [14, 4]]
        },{
          name: "Data B",
          data: [
          [16, 5], [14, 1], [14, 4], [12, 11]]
        },
          chart: {
          height: 350,
          type: 'scatter',
          zoom: {
            enabled: true,
            type: 'xy'
          }
        },
        xaxis: {
          tickAmount: 10,
          labels: {
            formatter: function(val) {
              return parseFloat(val).toFixed(1)
            }
          }
        },
        yaxis: {
          tickAmount: 7
        }
        };

        var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#chart"), options);
        chart.render();
```

Comment: Hi, did you find the solution? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: Hi, yes I created a jitter function and then added it to the Y value. Sadly I no longer have that code. But what I mean is before setting the Y value I looped all the values and for the ones that had the same or very close X and Y value I added some random "jitter" (extra value) to the Y value (just a small amount to make them separated). I also added the exact value without the jitter as another variable that shows on hover.